# For loops stop after one output?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

Write a function that will find all the anagrams of a word from a list. You will be given two inputs a word and an array with words.

Hi can some kind soul explain to me how this 2 function is different? One only returns the first value the for loops found.... why is that so?

```
def anagrams(word, words):
    for item in words:
        if sorted(item) == sorted(word):
            return [item]

def anagram(word, words):
    return [item for item in words if sorted(item) == sorted(word)]

print(anagrams('racer', ['crazer', 'carer', 'racar', 'caers', 'racer']))
print(anagram('racer', ['crazer', 'carer', 'racar', 'caers', 'racer']))
```

['carer']

['carer', 'racer']

Comment: `return` causes the function to exit. You'd use `yield` to do what you're trying to do; although that's a more advanced feature of the language.

Comment: If you want to get the same results (multiple matching words) and keep the similar `for-loop` then you need to add a `result (list)` to keep all matching anagrams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def anagram(word, words):
    return [item for item in words if sorted(item) == sorted(word)]
```

```py
def anagram(word, words):
    final_list = []
    for item in words:
        if sorted(item) == sorted(word):
            final_list.append(item)
    return final_list
```

Both will do the same work

your `anagrams` function return after finding one match which causes function to exit

`A return statement ends the execution of a function, and returns control to the calling function`

You can also use generator function

```py
def anagram(word, words):
    for item in words:
        if sorted(item) == sorted(word):
            yield item
   
print(anagram('racer', ['crazer', 'carer', 'racar', 'caers', 'racer']))

"""This returns a generator object, so you need to convert it to list"""

print(list(anagram('racer', ['crazer', 'carer', 'racar', 'caers', 'racer'])))
```